# PlayFramework cannot resolve symbol javascript

Tags: javascript, scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and in the following controller method it says that `Cannot resolve symbol javascript`.
The code is action for Javascript Router:

```
def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(
      JavaScriptReverseRouter("jsRoutes")(
        routes.javascript.BasicController.auto
      )
    ).as("text/javascript")
  }
```

Could this be fixed or it's just not a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Compile your project from command line using `activator compile`. If it compiles it should not be the problem.

Comment: but why the official doc says to add only import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing._

Comment: my version is 2.5
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting